# using testdisk to recover lost partitition

Tags: testdisk

I was fooling around with gparted and accidentally deleted a 4Tb partition I think I performed operations with the wrong partition selected I'm not sure So I launched testdisk and search for lost partitions, found the partition, listed it's files (which includes folders) and then selected all files and then upper case C for copy and then selected my 8Gb drive for the destination I was troubled to think how long the copying of the files was going to be running but I fell asleep and when I woke up a few hours later it had finished copying all the files and the directory structure was just like before the data loss I'm wondering why the operation completed so quickly Could it just be because my 8Tb drive is formatted to btrfs?

Comment: It's not the partition size but the amount of date being copied what matters. We don't know which amount of data you actually copied. Please proofread your question, as its currently written it doesn't make much sense. You copied from a 4Tb partition to a 8GB drive, so what has a 8Tb drive to do with it? I wonder why you didn't simply restore the partition, that would have been done in seconds.

Comment: Thanks I was just saying I selected a different physical disk as the destination I chose the "list files" option and then select all and then copy selected because I didn't know there was a restore partition option